# how can I read ann file provided by brat annotation toll and convert them to dataframe in python?

Tags: python, nlp, brat

I am working on the sequence tagging classification based IOB scheme,

firstly, I  want to kind of read my corpus and their labels, but the corpus has been saved in kind of format  called .ann file  that I have never worked as you here. it annotated using
https://brat.nlplab.org/
when I oped it i see this

```
T1  Claim 78 140    competition can effectively promote the development of economy
A1  Stance T1 Against
T2  MajorClaim 503 550  we should attach more importance to cooperation
T3  Premise 142 283 In order to survive in the competition, companies continue to improve their products and service, and as a result, the whole society prospers
T4  Claim 591 714   through cooperation, children can learn about interpersonal skills which are significant in the future life of all students
A2  Stance T4 For
T5  Premise 716 851 What we acquired from team work is not only how to achieve the same goal with others but more importantly, how to get along with others
T6  Premise 853 1086    During the process of cooperation, children can learn about how to listen to opinions of others, how to communicate with others, how to think comprehensively, and even how to compromise with other team members when conflicts occurred
T7  Premise 1088 1191   All of these skills help them to get on well with other people and will benefit them for the whole life
T8  Claim 1332 1376 competition makes the society more effective
A3  Stance T8 Against
T9  Premise 1212 1301   the significance of competition is that how to become more excellence to gain the victory
T10 Premise 1387 1492   when we consider about the question that how to win the game, we always find that we need the cooperation
T11 Premise 1549 1846   Take Olympic games which is a form of competition for instance, it is hard to imagine how an athlete could win the game without the training of his or her coach, and the help of other professional staffs such as the people who take care of his diet, and those who are in charge of the medical care
T12 Premise 1848 1915   The winner is the athlete but the success belongs to the whole team
T13 Claim 1927 1992 without the cooperation, there would be no victory of competition
A4  Stance T13 For
T14 Claim 2154 2231 a more cooperative attitudes towards life is more profitable in one's success
A5  Stance T14 For
R1  supports Arg1:T3 Arg2:T1    
R2  attacks Arg1:T1 Arg2:T2 
R3  supports Arg1:T5 Arg2:T4    
R4  supports Arg1:T6 Arg2:T4    
R5  supports Arg1:T7 Arg2:T4    
R6  supports Arg1:T9 Arg2:T8    
R7  supports Arg1:T11 Arg2:T12  
R8  supports Arg1:T12 Arg2:T13  
R9  supports Arg1:T10 Arg2:T13  
R10 supports Arg1:T4 Arg2:T2    
R11 attacks Arg1:T8 Arg2:T2 
R12 supports Arg1:T13 Arg2:T2   
R13 supports Arg1:T14 Arg2:T2
```

I want to easily decode that, and saved my data as dataframe  in this format:

sentence with their labels  ( claim or Premise or MAJORCLAIM  , as you see in the text)

something similar this format

[image]

sentences with their labels

I have tried to read  .txt file using this function

```
myList = []                #read the whole text from 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                text = f.read()
                myList.append(text)
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(myList),index=list(range(1,len(myList)+1)),columns=["Paragraph"])
```

but for this ann file provided by brat, I have no idea

Comment: Is this dataset publicly available? I really need this for research purposes.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that is the best approach

```
from brat_parser import get_entities_relations_attributes_groups

entities, relations, attributes, groups = get_entities_relations_attributes_groups("..\data\corpus02\essay01.ann")
```

using this apprach I can read the .ann file!!

```
{'T1': Entity(id='T1', type='Claim', span=((78, 140),), text='competition can effectively promote the development of economy'),
 'T2': Entity(id='T2', type='MajorClaim', span=((503, 550),), text='we should attach more importance to cooperation'),
 'T3': Entity(id='T3', type='Premise', span=((142, 283),), text='In order to survive in the competition, companies continue to improve their products and service, and as a result, the whole society prospers'),
 'T4': Entity(id='T4', type='Claim', span=((591, 714),), text='through cooperation, children can learn about interpersonal skills which are significant in the future life of all students'),
 'T5': Entity(id='T5', type='Premise', span=((716, 851),), text='What we acquired from team work is not only how to achieve the same goal with others but more importantly, how to get along with others'),
 'T6': Entity(id='T6', type='Premise', span=((853, 1086),), text='During the process of cooperation, children can learn about how to listen to opinions of others, how to communicate with others, how to think comprehensively, and even how to compromise with other team members when conflicts occurred'),
 'T7': Entity(id='T7', type='Premise', span=((1088, 1191),), text='All of these skills help them to get on well with other people and will benefit them for the whole life'),
 'T8': Entity(id='T8', type='Claim', span=((1332, 1376),), text='competition makes the society more effective'),
 'T9': Entity(id='T9', type='Premise', span=((1212, 1301),), text='the significance of competition is that how to become more excellence to gain the victory'),
 'T10': Entity(id='T10', type='Premise', span=((1387, 1492),), text='when we consider about the question that how to win the game, we always find that we need the cooperation'),
 'T11': Entity(id='T11', type='Premise', span=((1549, 1846),), text='Take Olympic games which is a form of competition for instance, it is hard to imagine how an athlete could win the game without the training of his or her coach, and the help of other professional staffs such as the people who take care of his diet, and those who are in charge of the medical care'),
 'T12': Entity(id='T12', type='Premise', span=((1848, 1915),), text='The winner is the athlete but the success belongs to the whole team'),
 'T13': Entity(id='T13', type='Claim', span=((1927, 1992),), text='without the cooperation, there would be no victory of competition'),
 'T14': Entity(id='T14', type='Claim', span=((2154, 2231),), text="a more cooperative attitudes towards life is more profitable in one's success")}
```

here is the result.  it should not be hard to convert  this to dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you need this dataframe formatted but regardless if you desire two columns, you can use a regex separator to find the first white space and use it as a delimiter when reading into a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.ann', sep='^([^\s]*)\s', engine='python', header=None).drop(0, axis=1)
```

This works with the above example you supplied if saved as a .ann file.

Comment: I have tried your approach...it was interesting that i can use pd.read_csv for reading .ann file but it does not give me what i want..